# Can't use template strings in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-strings

According to MDN, [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) *should* be working in Chrome, and by extension V8 on which Node.js is based on; but when I try the following I get a syntax error:

```
var name = 'coffee';
console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
```

running `node file.js` just results in a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Is there some kind of flag I need to enable to use this feature, or is it simply not implemented in node?

Comment: What version of node.js are you using? only v4.0.0 and above support template strings.

Comment: For whatever reason I have v0.12.7, and I downloaded it less than a month ago

Comment: @ElectricCoffee: A month ago, v0.12.7 was indeed the current version. Since then, Node.js and io.js have merged back together (io.js was a fork) and the first recombined release was deemed to be v4.0.0 (since io.js had been using semver and was at v3.3.1).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh they finally merged the projects, good

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Template strings were added in [NodeJS v4.0.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/). And I can confirm that they do work at least as far back as v4.1.1; I didn't bother to check v4.0.0, but I have no reason to doubt the linked announcement. No special runtime flag is required.

Comment: I could use this feature  at least on iojs 3.3.1